# Is there a better way to do this? Plotting lots of map markers

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I'm working on an android app.

I'm basically plotting a set of data to a map. They are camera locations. The map will shown a customised marker icon at the location, as well as contain a snippet of information when you click it.

I've a LOT of data to plot. It is Lat/Long coordinates.

I've just created an xml map fragment, id'd it, and dumped this into the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to avoid having a lot of similar variables, use a [`Collection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collection.html). I tend to use `ArrayList`s.

This is how I would address your situation:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> cameraLatLngs = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

// You should use a loop to add the LatLngs to the ArrayList
cameraLatLngs.add(new LatLng(51.6167, -3.9500));
cameraLatLngs.add(new LatLng(51.581, -3.9550));

for (int i = 0; i < cameraLatLngs.size(); i++) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("camera" + i)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.cctv)) 
    .snippet("<Camera Details>.").position(cameraLatLngs.get(0)));
```

I hope that answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

One time I tried creating markers for all the bus stops in my city... all 2,200 of them.  Needless to say, my phone would stumble a bit when I tried to pan around.  And when I zoomed out, the markers completely obscured the map.

I haven't had a chance to apply this solution yet, but if I ever revisit my bus app, I'll probably use [tile overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay).  You can provide different levels of detail at different zoom levels.  You could also detect map clicks near your camera locations to display your details.

Comment: This is v. interesting, will use this. Thanks :3